# Query that selects userId and average session duration for each user who has more than one session

Tags: sql

App usage data are kept in the following table:

Table `sessions`:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
userId INTEGER NOT NULL,
duration DECIMAL NOT NULL
```

I need a query that selects userId and average session duration for each user who has more than one session.

Answer (score 6):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT userId, AVG(duration)
FROM sessions
GROUP BY userId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT userId,AVG(duration),count(id) as num 
     FROM sessions GROUP BY userId HAVING count(id) > 0
```